# Making button shrink-wrap to size of pseudo element icon

Tags: css

Is it possible to make these buttons shrink-wrap to the size of their pseudo elements? Ideally using the current markup. There is also a `span` that should be factored into the equation.

Current result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

```css
body {
    padding: 20px 0 0 50px;
}
.button, .button:after {
    position: absolute;
}
.button {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.button:after {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(http://s27.postimg.org/lde21hwvz/test.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    content:"";
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like, .dislike {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.like:after, .dislike:after {
    background-position: 0 0;
    top: -13px;
}
.like:after {
    height: 22px;
    width: 40px;
}
.dislike:after {
    background-position: -60px 0;
    height: 12px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<a class="like button">
    <span>1234</span>
</a>
 <a class="dislike button">
    <span>1</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make these buttons shrink-wrap to the size of their
>   pseudo elements?

Unless you remove the pseudo-element from normal flow by `absolute` positioning.

Therefore, try removing the `position: absolute;` and instead add `display: inline-block;` from/to the pseudo-elements.

```css
body {
    padding: 20px 0 0 50px;
}
.button, .button:after {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.button:after {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(http://s27.postimg.org/lde21hwvz/test.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    content:"";
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like, .dislike {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.like:after, .dislike:after {
    background-position: 0 0;
    top: -13px;
}
.like:after {
    height: 22px;
    width: 40px;
}
.dislike:after {
    background-position: -60px 0;
    height: 12px;
    width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<a class="like button">
    <span>1234</span>
</a>
 <a class="dislike button">
    <span>1</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that. Is `inline-block` generally preferred when dealing with pseudo element images?

Comment: @MarkBoulder Not necessarily. In fact it is needed if you want to specify the dimensions of an inline-level element by `width`/`height` properties.